# "git subtree add" failed with "Unlink of file"

Tags: git, git-subtree

We want to go away from submodules and try on subtree system.

We have two repositories:

```
Qt-Integration
 - UEPlugin

Cos-Sim
 - CosmetologyTrainer
```

I want to add *Qt-Integration/UEPlugin* as subtree to *Cos-Sim/CosmetolgyTrainer* at **Plugins/Qt**

```
my@DESKTOP-I1D3N52 MINGW64 /c/my/5vid/Test/Cos-Sim(CosmetologyTrainer)
$ git subtree add --prefix=Plugins/Qt --squash git@github.com:5Vid/Qt-Integration.git UEPlugin
git fetch git@github.com:5Vid/Qt-Integration.git UEPlugin
From github.com:5Vid/Qt-Integration
 * branch            UEPlugin   -> FETCH_HEAD
Unlink of file 'Plugins' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

But i get *Unlink of file...*

In explorer I can see, that git has created path **Plugins/Qt**, and only .gitignore from *Qt-Integration/UEPlugin* exists.

If answer "n" and make *git status*, then you'll get this:

```
my@DESKTOP-I1D3N52 MINGW64 /c/my/5vid/Test/Cos-Sim (CosmetologyTrainer)
$ git status
On branch CosmetologyTrainer
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/CosmetologyTrainer'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   Plugins/Qt/.gitignore
        new file:   Plugins/Qt/Qt.uplugin
        new file:   Plugins/Qt/README.md
        new file:   Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Private/GameWithQtAppInstance.cpp
        new file:   Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Private/Qt.cpp
        new file:   Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Private/QtPrivatePCH.h
        new file:   Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Public/ConvertTemplate.h
        new file:   Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Public/GameWithQtAppInstance.h
        new file:   Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Public/Qt.h
        new file:   Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Public/QtConverters.h
        new file:   Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Qt.Build.cs

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    Plugins/Qt/Qt.uplugin
        deleted:    Plugins/Qt/README.md
        deleted:    Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Private/GameWithQtAppInstance.cpp
        deleted:    Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Private/Qt.cpp
        deleted:    Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Private/QtPrivatePCH.h
        deleted:    Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Public/ConvertTemplate.h
        deleted:    Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Public/GameWithQtAppInstance.h
        deleted:    Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Public/Qt.h
        deleted:    Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Public/QtConverters.h
        deleted:    Plugins/Qt/Source/Qt/Qt.Build.cs
```

I followed this [example](https://gist.github.com/kvnsmth/4688345)

In order to eliminate side effects, I did this all on the repository I've just cloned.

Can you help pls. 
I've spent too much time on this issue

Comment: Oh... You are doing this on Windows... Are sure this is supported on Windows? Also why the C++ tag?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher thats not allowed on windows? Editted, C++ removed, sry.

Comment: I don't know, but file links are not supported on NTFS. Only for folders.